# Group containing all powers of an element.

Tags: group-theory

This is probably a dumb question, but I've just started learning group theory and I can't be certain whether all groups would contain all powers of any of its elements. I know that by closure, I should have, for an element $a$ in a group $G$, $a \circ a^2 = a^3$, $a \circ a^3 = a^4$, etc. But does the law of composition allow $a \circ a$ to begin with?

Comment: Well, yes, the group operation is a map $G\times G\to G$.

Comment: You said it yourself: by closure I should have, for an element $a$ in a group $G$,  $a\circ a$ again in the group, because of closure.

Comment: I suspect that this has to do with that you might have learned of closure meaning that if we have $x$ and $y$ both as elements in our group, then $x\circ y$ should also be an element in our group.  Nowhere in that does it specify that $x$ and $y$ should be nonequal however!  By using different letters to represent them, we are explicitly allowing them to be nonequal but we are not *asserting* that they are nonequal.  By letting them both equal $a$, then we have $x\circ y$ is in the group, i.e. $a\circ a$ is in the group.

Comment: Not only the *positive* integer powers, $a^1,a^2,a^3,\ldots$, but the other integer powers $a^0,a^{-1},a^{-2},\ldots$ must also belong to the group $G$.

Answer (score 0):

Any group is a category with one element.

Definition : A category $C$ consists of

1. a class $ob(C)$ of objects
2. a class $mor(C)$ of morphisms, or arrows, or maps, between the objects.

Each morphism $f$ has a source object $a$ and a target object $b$ where $a$ and $b$ are in $ob(C)$. We write $f: a\to b$, and we say "$f$ is a morphism from $a$ to $b$". We write $mor(a, b)$ (or $mor_{C}(a, b)$ when there may be confusion about to which category $mor(a, b)$ refers) to denote the $mor$-class of all morphisms from $a$ to $b$.

for every three objects $a, b$ and $c$, a binary operation $mor(a, b)\times mor(b, c)\to mor(a, c)$ called composition of morphisms; the composition of $f : a \to b$ and $g : b\to c$ is written as $g\circ f$ or $gf$.
such that the following axioms hold:

(associativity) if $f : a \to b, g : b\to c$ and $h : c\to d$ then $h \circ (g \circ f) = (h \circ g) \circ f$, and

(identity) for every object $x$, there exists a morphism $1_{x} : x \to x$  called the identity morphism for $x$, such that for every morphism $f : a\ to x$ and every morphism $g : x\ to b$, we have $1_{x}\circ f = f$ and $g \circ 1_{x}= g$.

So let $G$ be arbitrary group, consider $C$ be a category with $ob(C)=\{G\}$ and $mor(G, G)=\{g\in G\}$
(please check this example is category)

So, the composition of this category has the form 
\begin{align*}
\circ : mor(G, G) \times mor(G, G) \to mor(G, G)\\
(g, g') \mapsto g'\circ g
\end{align*}

Now for all $ g\in G$ the composition $g\circ g$ is well defined and it is in $G$.

Comment: I think ithis might not be the most helpful way to respond to the OP.  If someone is confused about whether a group contains all the powers of its elements, approaching it by treating a group as "a category with one element" would risk adding a greater level of confusion.

Comment: If we know the basics of any concept, the confusion will eventually be removed. So I think it's very useful to create a deep thought challenge.